# Finding Row Number of a change made via changetype = other

Tags: google-apps-script, changetype

I need to be able to call the row number where a change was made, when `changeType == "OTHER"`. Below is a test script (with runNotify triggered via on change) that should email me the row number of the row where the change was made, however it only ever returns "1" as the row number. What am I missing that keeps it from returning the row number of the changed row?

```
function notify(request) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("youremailhere.com", "Row Added", request.editedRow);
}

function runNotify(e) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("Y:Y");
    if (e.changeType == "OTHER") {
    var request = findRow(e);
    notify(request);
    }
}

function findRow(e) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("Y:Y");
    if (e.changeType == "OTHER") {
    this.editedRow = range.getRow();
    return this;
  }
}
```

Working code that will call the row being edited following a change made in App Script when used with onChange trigger:

```
function notify(request) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@gmail.com", "Row Added", request.activeRow);
}

function runNotify(e) {
    if (e.changeType == "EDIT") {
      var request = findTheRow(e);
      notify(request);
    }   else {
      return;
      }
}

function findTheRow(e) {
  var sSht = e.source;
  var sht = sSht.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRng = sht.getActiveRange();
  this.activeRow = activeRng.getRow();
  return this;
}
```

Comment: onChange event object don't have the range property. See [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change). The only trigger that has range property is onEdit. Is there any reason why you didn't use onEdit() trigger?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I will be using some of this test script as part of a larger script. We are using AppSheet to input/edit the sheet the script is tied to. The script is used to create a gcal event. The onChange trigger is the only trigger that will pick up changes implemented via AppSheet. Unfortunately, onEdit does not respond to changes made via AppSheet. So, I can act on new submissions by calling `getLastRow()` but I don't have a way to run the script on a row that has been edited (since there has been data entered below & it's no longer the last row).

Comment: @NikkoJ. Is there any way whatsoever to determine the row number from the onChange event object?

Comment: Does the AppSheet activate or select the range in Google Sheets when making changes?

Comment: YES!!! Thank you @NikkoJ. thats just what I needed. I will attach the working code to my original question.

Comment: Could you post the working code as answer? This will help other people with the same issue that their issue can be resolved.

Comment: Yes, I will. Thanks for your help in finding a resolution!

Answer (score 0):

Code that will return the number of the edited row when a change is made via AppSheet:

```
function notify(request) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@gmail.com", "Row Added", request.activeRow);
}

function runNotify(e) {
    if (e.changeType == "EDIT") {
      var request = findTheRow(e);
      notify(request);
    }   else {
      return;
      }
}

function findTheRow(e) {
  var sSht = e.source;
  var sht = sSht.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRng = sht.getActiveRange();
  this.activeRow = activeRng.getRow();
  return this;
}
```